# Find points in cells through pandas dataframes of coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, points, spatial-query

I have to find which points are inside a grid of square cells, given the points coordinates and the coordinates of the bounds of the cells, through two pandas dataframes. 
I'm calling **dfc** the dataframe containing the code and the boundary coordinates of the cells (I simplify the problem, in the real analysis I have a big grid with geographical points and tons of points to check):

```
Code,minx,miny,maxx,maxy
01,0.0,0.0,2.0,2.0
02,2.0,2.0,3.0,3.0
```

and **dfp** the dataframe containing an Id and the coordinates of the points:

```
Id,x,y
0,1.5,1.5
1,1.1,1.1
2,2.2,2.2
3,1.3,1.3
4,3.4,1.4
5,2.0,1.5
```

Now I would like to perform a search returning in dfc dataframe a new column (called 'GridCode') of the grid in which the point is in. The cells should be perfectly squared, so I would like to perform an analysis through:

```
a = np.where(
            (dfp['x'] > dfc['minx']) &
            (dfp['x'] < dfc['maxx']) &
            (dfp['y'] > dfc['miny']) &
            (dfp['y'] < dfc['maxy']),
            r2['Code'],
            'na')
```

avoiding several loops on the dataframes. The lenghts of the dataframes are not the same. The resulting dataframe should be as follows:

```
   Id    x    y GridCode
0   0  1.5  1.5   01
1   1  1.1  1.1   01
2   2  2.2  2.2   02
3   3  1.3  1.3   01
4   4  3.4  1.4   na
5   5  2.0  1.5   na
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a better way, but since this has been sitting out there for awhile..

Using Pandas boolean indexing to filter the dfc data frame instead of np.where()

```
def findGrid(dfp):  
    c = dfc[(dfp['x'] > dfc['minx']) &
            (dfp['x'] < dfc['maxx']) &
            (dfp['y'] > dfc['miny']) &
            (dfp['y'] < dfc['maxy'])].Code

    if len(c) == 0:        
        return None
    else:        
        return c.iat[0]
```

Then use the pandas apply() function

```
dfp['GridCode'] = dfp.apply(findGrid,axis=1)
```

Will yield this

```
    Id  x   y   GridCode
0   0   1.5 1.5 1
1   1   1.1 1.1 1
2   2   2.2 2.2 2
3   3   1.3 1.3 1
4   4   3.4 1.4 NaN
5   5   2.0 1.5 NaN
```