# Pandas find value in interval

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas if I have transaction data in dataframe (transdf) that looks like this:

```
OrderId, ShippmentSegmentsDays
1      , 1
2      , 3
3      , 4
4      , 10
```

And I have another df (segmentdf) that specify intervals:

```
ShippmentSegmentDaysStart , ShippmentSegmentDaysEnd , ShippmentSegment
-9999999                  , 0                       , 'On-Time'
0                         , 1                       , '1 day late'
1                         , 2                       , '2 days late'
2                         , 3                       , '3 days late'
3                         , 9999999                 , '>3 days late'
```

And I need to add one more column which is based on "ShippmentSegmentsDays" and "ShippmentSegment". So basically for each row from "transdf" I need to check "ShippmentSegmentsDays" value in which interval can be found from "segmentdf"

As a result the "transdf" should look like this:

```
OrderId, ShippmentSegmentsDays, ShippmentSegment
1      , 1                    , '1 day late'
2      , 0                    , 'On-Time'
3      , 4                    , '>3 days late'
4      , 10                   , '>3 days late'
```

Can anyone give me an advice how this situation can be handled?

Thanks!
Stefan

Comment: This looks similar to a problem I answered awhile ago.  Give it a look to see if it helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464394/find-points-in-cells-through-pandas-dataframes-of-coordinates/27466566#27466566

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.apply(args)` to apply a function to each row in the `transdf` data frame if you know that the rules set in the `segmentdf` are static and don't change. Perhaps the following code snippet may help you. I haven't tested this so be wary, but I think it should get you started in the right direction.

```
# create a series of just the data from the 'ShippmentSegmentDays' column
seg_days_df = trends['ShippmentSegmentDays']

# Create a new column, 'ShippmentSegment', in 'transdf' data frame by calling
# our utility function on the series created above.
transdf['ShippmentSegment'] = seg_days_df.apply(calc_ship_segment, axis=1)

# Utility function to define the rules set in the 'segmentdf' data frame
def calc_ship_segment(num):
     if not num:
         return 'On Time'
     elif num == 1:
         return '1 Day Late'
     elif num == 2:
         return '2 Days Late'
     elif num == 3:
         return '3 Days Late'
     else:
         return '>3 Days Late'
```

Comment: `!num` isn't valid Python syntax, I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but I had the same issue. Pandas offers an [Interval function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html) that worked for me.