# Assign numpy array of points to a 2D square grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm going beyond [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464394/find-points-in-cells-through-pandas-dataframes-of-coordinates) previous question because of speed problems. I have an array of Lat/Lon coordinates of points, and I would like to assign them to an index code derived from a 2D square grid of equal size cells. This is an example of how it would be. Let's called `points` my first array containing coordinates (called them [x y] pairs) of six points:

```
points = [[ 1.5  1.5]
 [ 1.1  1.1]
 [ 2.2  2.2]
 [ 1.3  1.3]
 [ 3.4  1.4]
 [ 2.   1.5]]
```

Then I have another array containing the coordinates of the vertices of a grid of two cells in the form [minx,miny,maxx,maxy]; let's call it `bounds`:

```
bounds = [[ 0.  0.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  3.  3.]]
```

I would like to find which points are in which boundary, and then assign a code derived from the `bounds` array index (in this case the first cell has code 0, the second 1 and so on...). Since the cells are squares, the easiest way to compute if each point is in each cell is to evaluate:

```
x > minx & x < maxx & y > miny & y < maxy
```

So that the resulting array would appear as:

```
results = [0 0 1 0 NaN NaN]
```

where NaN means that the point is outside cells. The number of elements in my real case is of the order of finding 10^6 points into 10^4 cells. Is there a way to do this kind of things in a fast way using numpy arrays?

EDIT: to clarify, the `results` array expected means that the first points is inside the first cell (0 index of the `bounds` array) so the second, and the first is inside the second cell of the `bounds` array and so on...

Comment: Is `[0 0 1 0 NaN NaN]` the result of preceding `bounds` and `points`? and can you explain how you used `bounds`?

Comment: Yes, intersecting each point with the two cells and getting the corresponding cell code.

Comment: If `bounds` is an array of [minx miny maxx maxy] values, the problem is to implement the function `x > minx & x < maxx & y > miny & y < maxy` in order to determined that, for instance, the first point is in the first cell of the `bounds` array. Hope it helps.

Comment: I get it but `bounds` has 2 item!!! how you used that 2 item?

Comment: Just iterating over them. I mean, the problem here is implementing the search function over the bounds array, which has two items because it contains two cells. The first item has index 0 and the second 1, so that I would like to assign them to each point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a vectorized approach to your problem. It should speed things up significantly.

```
import numpy as np
def findCells(points, bounds):
    # make sure points is n by 2 (pool.map might send us 1D arrays)
    points = points.reshape((-1,2))

    # check for each point if all coordinates are in bounds
    # dimension 0 is bound
    # dimension 1 is is point
    allInBounds = (points[:,0] > bounds[:,None,0])
    allInBounds &= (points[:,1] > bounds[:,None,1])
    allInBounds &= (points[:,0] < bounds[:,None,2])
    allInBounds &= (points[:,1] < bounds[:,None,3])


    # now find out the positions of all nonzero (i.e. true) values
    # nz[0] contains the indices along dim 0 (bound)
    # nz[1] contains the indices along dim 1 (point)
    nz = np.nonzero(allInBounds)

    # initialize the result with all nan
    r = np.full(points.shape[0], np.nan)
    # now use nz[1] to index point position and nz[0] to tell which cell the
    # point belongs to
    r[nz[1]] = nz[0]
    return r

def findCellsParallel(points, bounds, chunksize=100):
    import multiprocessing as mp
    from functools import partial

    func = partial(findCells, bounds=bounds)

    # using python3 you could also do 'with mp.Pool() as p:'  
    p = mp.Pool()
    try:
        return np.hstack(p.map(func, points, chunksize))
    finally:
        p.close()

def main():
    nPoints = 1e6
    nBounds = 1e4

    # points = np.array([[ 1.5, 1.5],
    #                    [ 1.1, 1.1],
    #                    [ 2.2, 2.2],
    #                    [ 1.3, 1.3],
    #                    [ 3.4, 1.4],
    #                    [ 2. , 1.5]])

    points = np.random.random([nPoints, 2])

    # bounds = np.array([[0,0,2,2],
    #                    [2,2,3,3]])

    # bounds = np.array([[0,0,1.4,1.4],
    #                    [1.4,1.4,2,2],
    #                    [2,2,3,3]])

    bounds = np.sort(np.random.random([nBounds, 2, 2]), 1).reshape(nBounds, 4)

    r = findCellsParallel(points, bounds)
    print(points[:10])
    for bIdx in np.unique(r[:10]):
        if np.isnan(bIdx):
            continue
        print("{}: {}".format(bIdx, bounds[bIdx]))
    print(r[:10])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Edit:**
Trying it with your amount of data gave me a `MemoryError`. You can avoid that and even speed things up a little more if you use `multiprocessing.Pool` with its `map` function, see updated code.

Result:

```
>time python test.py
[[ 0.69083585  0.19840985]
 [ 0.31732711  0.80462512]
 [ 0.30542996  0.08569184]
 [ 0.72582609  0.46687164]
 [ 0.50534322  0.35530554]
 [ 0.93581095  0.36375539]
 [ 0.66226118  0.62573407]
 [ 0.08941219  0.05944215]
 [ 0.43015872  0.95306899]
 [ 0.43171644  0.74393729]]
9935.0: [ 0.31584562  0.18404152  0.98215445  0.83625487]
9963.0: [ 0.00526106  0.017255    0.33177741  0.9894455 ]
9989.0: [ 0.17328876  0.08181912  0.33170444  0.23493507]
9992.0: [ 0.34548987  0.15906761  0.92277442  0.9972481 ]
9993.0: [ 0.12448765  0.5404578   0.33981119  0.906822  ]
9996.0: [ 0.41198261  0.50958195  0.62843379  0.82677092]
9999.0: [ 0.437169    0.17833114  0.91096133  0.70713434]
[ 9999.  9993.  9989.  9999.  9999.  9935.  9999.  9963.  9992.  9996.]

real 0m 24.352s
user 3m  4.919s
sys  0m  1.464s
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually one point can be only in one and one single bound...so it should work fine!

Comment: @Fiabetto you might want to have a look at my answer again. I'm now down to 24s on my machine with 1e6 points and 1e4 bounds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested loop with to check the condition and yield the result as a generator :

```
points = [[ 1.5  1.5]
 [ 1.1  1.1]
 [ 2.2  2.2]
 [ 1.3  1.3]
 [ 3.4  1.4]
 [ 2.   1.5]]

bounds = [[ 0.  ,0. , 2.,  2.],
 [ 2.  ,2.  ,3.,  3.]]

import numpy as np

def pos(p,b):
  for x,y in p:
    flag=False
    for index,dis in enumerate(b):
      minx,miny,maxx,maxy=dis
      if x > minx and x < maxx and y > miny and y < maxy :
        flag=True
        yield index
    if not flag:
        yield 'NaN'


print list(pos(points,bounds))
```

result :

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 'NaN', 'NaN']
```

Comment: Thanks Kasra, but maybe is there a typo? The result list length should be equal to the length of the points input array.

Comment: @Fiabetto Welcome. yeah :) it was just a typo!

Comment: Thanks for your help I'm testing your method on speed time compare to my old one! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
import numpy as np

points = np.random.rand(10,2)

xmin = [0.25,0.5]
ymin = [0.25,0.5]

results = np.zeros(len(points))

for i in range(len(xmin)):
     bool_index_array = np.greater(points, [xmin[i],ymin[i]])
     print "boolean index of (x,y) greater (xmin, ymin): ", bool_index_array
     indicies_of_true_true = np.where(bool_index_array[:,0]*bool_index_array[:,1]==1)[0]
     print "indices of [True,True]: ", indicies_of_true_true
     results[indicies_of_true_true] += 1

print "results: ", results

[out]: [ 1.  1.  1.  2.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

This uses the lower boundaries to catagorize your points into the groups:

- 1 (if xmin[0] < x <= xmin[1] & ymin[0] < y <= ymin[1])
- 2 (if x > xmin[1] & y > ymin[1])
- 0 if none of the conditions above are fullfilled